# MacOS X very slow, while Windows 10 is snappy

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, high-sierra, ssd

I have a fairly old (late 2009) MacBook, I replaced the HDD with an SSD drive, and installed High Sierra on it.
It ran slowly but I assumed it was because it's old, but I installed Windows 10 on it, and it's pretty snappy, not like a modern i7 CPU, but, much, much faster than MacOS X, which is surprising.
Could I be missing a setting or something?
I enabled TRIM support.

Comment: Does Activity Monitor show using CPU or memory ?

Comment: This might essentially be due to the requirements of both OSes. Windows 10's hardware requirements are low compared to Apple's OSes. For instance *min 1Go RAM* for Windows 10 vs min 2Go RAM for High Sierra. But High Sierra has other requirements when it comes to processor, preferred graphic card memory, etc... Basically, Microsoft tries to adapt its OS to the many many hardwares configs while Apple owns both the OS and hardware production line (and thus they do not need to optimise their OS for older HW models that are nearly obsolete)

Comment: But short answer, even Yosemite or Mavericks would make your Mac slow. Apple's OSes are at fault. A Windows or Linux OS would run much faster

Comment: I didn't see a very high resource usage, but I may have checked in the wrong time, I'll check again when I get next to it.

Comment: I checked and it seems that kernel_task is using around 130 CPU and I have around 60-70% Sys CPU usage.